# Smooth Text Borders

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing

I have the image below:

[image]

I want to smoothen its borders but not removing the curves. I want it to look naturally as the second image. How should I do it  in Python?

[image]

Code:

```
 from PIL import Image
 import numpy as np

 image_counter = 1
 path = 'sample/' + str(image_counter) + '.png'
 image = Image.open(path).convert('1')
 image = np.array(image)

 #Image manipulation goes here.



 image = Image.fromarray(image)
 image.save('output.png')
```

If there are algorithms that approximates curve into lines (e.g Douglas Peucker Algorithm), I want it in reverse. I want an algorithm that smoothens the jagged lines into curves. Is that possible?

Comment: Would reading the text by code and outputting the same string to an image fulfil your needs?

Comment: @zabop yes, the string should be the same. I just want to imitate a real scanned old image using image processing techniques.

Comment: @zabop please see my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

The following I think should work:
Take the 2D FFT of the image, cut off high frequency components, which cause the wiggly bits on the borders, inverse transform it back, and get a smoothened image.

Below is an implementation which did not give the expected result but might be useful anyway.

---

After your  `#Image manipulation goes here` line:

imagefft=np.fft.fft2(image)

Kill off high frequency bits with this function, which zeros out values above the 85th percentile value:

```
def smoothen(this):
    return this * (np.percentile(this, 85) > this)
```

Apply the `smoothen` function to the absolute value of the 2D inverse Fourier transform, and transform the resulting array back:

```
imageres = (np.real(np.fft.ifft2(smoothen(np.real(imagefft)+np.imag(imagefft))))-
            np.imag(np.fft.ifft2(smoothen(np.real(imagefft)+np.imag(imagefft)))))
```

Using `plt.imshow(imageres)` we get:

[image]

Increase contrast:

```
tminval = np.percentile(imageres, 10)
maxval = np.percentile(imageres, 90)
pixvals = np.clip(imageres, minval, maxval)
pixvals = ((pixvals - minval) / (maxval - minval)) * 255
```

Check result with `plt.imshow(pixvals)`:

[image]

This obviously did not work.

*I leave this answer here because implementation is admittedly wrong, theory is right I believe, so it might be useful anyway. Feel free to edit this.*

Comment: Thank you for giving me somehow an idea.